# How to track Email read duration using php?

Tags: php, email, html-email

I Want to track how many seconds user spends on a mail sent via me.
I have used a php script for it.

```
<?php
// Time the request
$st = time();
$t = $st;
$ft = $st + 30;
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
syslog(LOG_ERR,"URL : ".$actual_link);

while($st < $ft)
{
    // Did the connection fail?
    echo "HI \n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
     if(connection_status() != 0)
        {
          $duration1 = time() - $t;
          syslog(LOG_ERR,"SKIM : User Stopped For TIME: ".$duration1);
          break;
         }

    // Sleep for 1 seconds
    sleep(1);
    $st = $st + 1;
}
if($st >= $ft)
{
   $duration = $st - $t;
   syslog(LOG_ERR,"READ : User Stopped For TIME: ".$duration);
 }
?>
```

It is invoked via HTML in the content of mail like

```
<body>
<img src="http://url.../openduration.php/>
</body>
```

Now the time duration of reading the mail shows always mostly 23 seconds irrespective of the time duration  I take to read it. I tried closing the mail before after too but no effect. Although the script works perfect when I try it on a webpage on local server.I tried for Gmail only.

Comment: are you talking about the loading time of email ?

Comment: No after loading the essential contents I invoke the script.
Basically for tracking  the read duration.

Comment: Most webmail clients such as Gmail and Outlook use image proxies to asynchronously load images in each email. Since the images are loaded this way they will continue loading until the connection times out even if the reader has moved on from the message. However there are still many email clients that allow read time to measured this way so using a [hosted service](https://shiftmail.io) will cut the dozens of hours catching all of these edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your are talking about this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['start'] = time();


/*here goes the code of email*/

$_SESSION['end'] = time(); 
echo "Start:".$_SESSION['start']."--"."End:".$_SESSION['end']."</br>";
echo "Total Execution time is : ".date("H:i:s",$_SESSION['end']-$_SESSION['start']);

?>
```

Comment: That is fine but I think here is if condition problem as it enters after 23 second always..

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do what you want. Gmail caches all the images in a mail, so I suppose that after 23 seconds of not receiving anything it just timed out the request by itself

Comment: Actually sometimes It comes READ: More than 30 Sec too...And Less than 23 seconds too..I don't nw why it happens..

Comment: Well, It really doesn't matter. Any information you receive is from gmail automated processing of the mail, not the user.

Comment: Actually I think I am sending "HI" in this scenario So it is recieving it every second So How can it timeout?

Comment: As I said Gmail probably closes the connection after some time based on it's own timeout settings. By "anything" I meant a real image